# How to select range of cells instead of only 2 cells for strBody variable?

Tags: excel, vba

VBA watch window shows "type mismatch" and Empty for values `strBody` variable and value when running this script.  I've confirmed the email portion of this script works.  I simply cannot select the range of cells I want.  Help?

I'd like to be able to select a range for the `strBody` variable.

If I replace the `strBody` variable with the following, everything works:

`strBody = Str(Sheet1.Cells(1, 1)) & Str(Sheet1.Cells(1, 2))`

```
Sub send_email()
Dim NewMail As Object
Dim MailConfig As Object
Dim SMTP_Config As Variant
Dim strSubject As String
Dim strFrom As String
Dim strTo As String
Dim strCc As String
Dim strBcc As String
Dim strBody As Variant

strSubject = "Mail from Excel"
strFrom = "email@gmail.com"
strTo = "email@gmail.com"
strCc = ""
strBcc = ""
strBody = Str(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B2"))
```

Comment: What is in those cells (text)? You most likely don't want the [`Str`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/str-function) function. The type mismatch is because `Range("A1:B2")` is a call to the default member, i.e. is `Range("A1:B2").Value`, which returns a 2D array (and you can't pass an array to `Str`).

Comment: Is there a benefit to dimming all of these variables just to to `.To = strTo` later down the road? Seems like you can just input these values when they are needed which would erase the need for just about all of the code you shared. It's not redundant, but very close to it. That is said without knowing the context so I could be wrong

Comment: @BigBen - I am hoping to post a table of data with data labels into the body of an email that will be sent daily.  I am using powerquery to automatically refresh the table each day.  I did not write this code, I am simply following a tutorial and modifying for my needs.  You can see the tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zNGd_9jedbQ

Comment: Assuming that all four cells in the range `A1:B2` have values, are you positive that `Str(Sheet1.Cells(1, 1)) & Str(Sheet1.Cells(1, 2))` actually returns all that data? AFAIK, It should just return what's in `A1` and `B2`, but leaves out anything in `A2` and `B1`...

Comment: @BruceWayne You are correct, 
    Str(Sheet1.Cells(1, 1)) & Str(Sheet1.Cells(1, 2)) 
returns only the data in A1 and B2.  That's why I am trying to target a bigger range but not having any luck.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your data, you might consider building a UDF:

```
...
strBody = build_body(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B2"))
End Sub

Function build_body(rng As Range, Optional delimiter As String = " ") As String
Dim cel As Range
Dim tmpStr As String
For Each cel In rng.Cells
    If tmpStr <> "" Then tmpStr = tmpStr & delimiter & cel.Value
    If tmpStr = "" Then tmpStr = cel.Value
Next cel
Debug.Print tmpStr
build_body = tmpStr
End Function
```

With sample data:

[image]

Outputs: `A1, B1, A2, B2`.

Doing just `Str(Sheet1.Cells(1, 1)) & Str(Sheet1.Cells(1, 2))` would output `A1B1`.